# Step by step derivation of vector cross-product expression

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

### Equation 1

$$\vec{a}  * \vec{b} = (|\vec{a}| | \vec{b}| sin θ)ň $$

### Equation 2

$$\vec{a}  * \vec{b} = (a_yb_z - a_zb_y)î - (a_xb_z - a_zb_x)ĵ + (a_xb_y - a_yb_x)k̂ $$

I have managed to figure out and understand how to get all the terms within the brackets. However, I do not understand how to get the + and - symbols between the brackets.

### Additional Information

$$ î * ĵ = k̂  $$

$$ ĵ * k̂ = î $$

$$ k̂ * î = ĵ $$

$$ ĵ * î = -k̂ $$

$$ k̂ * ĵ = -î $$

$$ î * k̂ = -ĵ $$

$$ î * î = ĵ * ĵ = k̂ * k̂ = 0 $$

Thank you!

Further Update

So, to begin...

$$\vec{a} = a_xî+a_yĵ+a_zk̂$$

$$\vec{b} = b_xî+b_yĵ+b_zk̂$$

Multiplying out vector a and b gives 9 terms:

$$a_xîb_xî + a_xîb_yĵ  +  a_xîb_zk̂ + a_yĵb_xî + a_yĵb_yĵ  +  a_yĵb_zk̂ + a_zk̂b_xî + a_zk̂b_yĵ  +  a_zk̂b_zk̂           $$

The 3 terms in which the unit vectors (î, ĵ and k̂) multiply by themselves, are equal to zero, and hence disappear. For example, the following will disappear:

$$ a_xîb_xî  $$

Therefore, we are left with 6 terms:
$$a_xîb_yĵ  +  a_xîb_zk̂ + a_yĵb_xî  +  a_yĵb_zk̂ + a_zk̂b_xî + a_zk̂b_yĵ         $$

Next, I use the information under additional information to get:

$$a_xb_yk̂ + a_xb_z(-ĵ) + a_yb_x(-k̂) + a_yb_zî + a_zb_xĵ + a_zb_y(-î)         $$

Now, I group the like terms together by the unit vector.

$$ (a_xb_y -  a_yb_x)k̂ + (a_xb_z-a_zb_x)ĵ + (a_yb_z - a_zb_y)î $$

The above line is not correct (but what I keep getting). The book states equation 2 is what I should get. Where have I gone wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please use MathJax to format math.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Thank you, I will do this now.

Comment: I've edited with MathJax. Hope this is okay.

Comment: Have you tried writing $a = a_xî + a_y  ĵ + a_zk̂ $ (analogously for $b$) and multiplying out?

Comment: Hi, I tried this before posting. I get the correct terms but I don't know how to add them together. I'll edit my post. Just need a bit of time as it takes me a while to edit due to being new.

Comment: @PassionFruitChemistry "*I group the like terms together*" But $a_xb_z(-ĵ) + a_zb_xĵ = \color{red}{-}(a_xb_z - a_zb_x)ĵ$.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you know that $(\vec a+\vec b)\times \vec c = (\vec a\times\vec c) + (\vec b\times\vec c)$?

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for solving. This makes a lot more sense now. Just to clarify for anyone else, I grouped the like terms wrong above. By doing the correct grouping, equation 2 is obtained.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I know that. I see where I went wrong now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3),b=(b_1,b_2,b_3).$

I'll assume you are familiar with the dot product identity (otherwise, prove it by the law of cosines):

$$a \cdot b=|a| |b| \cos \theta.$$

Note that from your equation 2,

$$|a \times b|^2=(a_2b_3-b_2a_3)^2+(b_1a_3-a_1b_3)^2+(a_1b_2-b_1a_2)^2.$$

Some clever reorganization of this messy expression will get you the following:

$$|a \times b|^2=(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)^2,$$

which can now be written in terms of the dot product as

$$|a \times b|^2=|a|^2|b|^2-(a\cdot b)^2=|a|^2|b|^2-|a|^2|b|^2\cos^2 \theta=|a|^2|b|^2\sin^2\theta$$

Square root both sides and conclude.

Comment: Hi, it seems to me you derived Equation 1 but without ň. I was trying to get to Equation 2 from Equation 1 and using the equations under Additional Information. Nonetheless, this is a very useful answer I will refer back to later, so please do not delete! Thank you.

Comment: @PassionFruitChemistry Correct, this is the derivation for the *magnitude* of the cross product (as per equation 1), not the direction.  Also, you can see that you need some extra facts beyond "additional info" because you need to relate the angle $\theta$ with equation 2.

Comment: How did you define $ň$? It should be a unit vector that is orthogonal to both $a,b$ and follows the right-hand rule.

Comment: Hello, that makes sense. I've defined ň as the unit vector perpendicular/orthogonal to the plane defined by a and b. What I've understood is when you multiply two vectors (to obtain the cross product), the resultant vector is perpendicular to both a and b (that is the direction).

Comment: @PassionFruitChemistry Yes, there are two ways to be orthogonal. The cross product follows the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)